# Can't get CalendarView to setDate to current date

Tags: android, calendarview

I searched around on here and google trying to find something that can help me focus the current date of the system. I tried using the .setDate(long,boolean,boolean) But it doesn't seem to work.

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void Currentdate(View view) {
    CalendarView cal = new CalendarView(this);
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    cal.setDate(time,false,true);


}
```

}

my xml

```
    <CalendarView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:firstDayOfWeek="2"
    android:weekNumberColor="#ff8b8b88"
    android:clickable="true"/>

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Current date"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/calendarView"
    android:onClick="Currentdate"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, are you running this code on the UI thread? Are you sure this code block is actually running? If you post more of the source code that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even cast your CalendarView into your code, try this:

```
CalendarView cal = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
```

instead of:

```
CalendarView cal = new CalendarView(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
private void Currentdate() {
    CalendarView cal = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    cal.setDate(time,false,true);
}
```